# Arrays of pointers example

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am studying [this](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node10.html) webpage on pointers. The **Arrays of Pointers** section says the following:

> We can have arrays of pointers since pointers are variables.
>
> Example use:
>
> ***Sort lines of text of different length.***
>
> **NOTE:** Text can't be moved or compared in a single operation.
>
> ***Arrays of Pointers*** are a data representation that will cope efficiently and conveniently with variable length text lines.
>
> How can we do this?:
>
> - Store lines end-to-end in one big char array (Fig. 9.4). \n will delimit lines.
> - Store pointers in a different array where each pointer points to 1st char of each new line.
> - Compare two lines using strcmp() standard library function.
> - If 2 lines are out of order -- swap pointer in pointer array (not text).
>   [image]
>   This eliminates:
> - complicated storage management.
> - high overheads of moving lines.

I don't understand what's going on with the two pointer arrays `P` in Fig. 9.4. It says in the fourth point that, if 2 lines are out of order, then swap the pointers in the pointer array, but it doesn't seem like the pointers in `P` were swapped at all; rather, it seems like the pointers are exactly the same – pointer at position `0` of `P` points to `ABC`, pointer at position `1` of `P` points to `DEF`, pointer at position `2` of `P` points to `CAT`. What's going on here?

Comment: You only have a single array `P`, and you swap the elements of the array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I understand that.

Comment: I guess the picture is wrong - maybe the person who made it just swapped the two boxes instead of the pointer-arrows - maybe to illustrate correct order. But seems simply wrong to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an error in that picture. The idea with the crossed arrows is to demonstrate that on the right hand side the strings CAT and DEF are not moved but the author has mistakenly swapped those strings on the right.

Since the page was written in 1999 and has not been fixed in 22 years, maybe you should be looking for better resources...

Comment: Our lecturer directed us to this page.